# Multiplying 2 column values in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE updatesql nvarchar(MAX)

SET @updatesql = N'update '+ @TableName +'  SET      
 Total_Revenue=CAST(COALESCE(Total_Hours,0) AS FLOAT) * CAST(COALESCE(Rate,0) AS FLOAT)
 where associate_ID='+ @associateId 

 EXECUTE  (@updatesql)
```

This is giving the error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '27.72081' to data type int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting numeric values to VARCHAR inside your dynamic statement.  Remove the CASTs and it should be good.

Your resulting statement should read something like this when printed:

```
update table1 SET      
 Total_Revenue=COALESCE(Total_Hours,0) * COALESCE(Rate,0)
 where associate_ID=1;
```

You should also use 0.0 in your COALESCE so that your formula multiplies a decimal type with another decimal type.  As is you are multiplying a decimail and an INT.  (I assume that Total_Hours and/or Rate is a decimal type based on the value in the error message you provided.)

**Update after question edit:**

Your CAST is in the wrong place.  You can't COALESCE a VARCHAR and an INT.  Your statement should now look something like this:

```
update table1 SET      
 Total_Revenue=COALESCE(CAST(Total_Hours AS FLOAT),0.0) * COALESCE(CAST(Rate AS FLOAT),0.0)
 where associate_ID=1;
```

Comment: How to do that in dynamic SQL. Total_Hours and Rate values are Varchar in the table. I have used CAST to make it to float. Please check my edit. The query executes without dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of `associate_id`.  Pass it in as a parameter:

```
SET @updatesql = N'
update '+ @TableName +' 
    SET Total_Revenue=CAST(COALESCE(Total_Hours,0) AS FLOAT) * CAST(COALESCE(Rate,0) AS FLOAT)
    WHERE associate_ID = @associateId';


EXEC sp_executesql @updatesql, N'@associate_id int', @associate_id=@associate_id;
```

Comment: I am getting the error because of the Rate column. How to do the multiplication converting to Varchar?